# EventBridge Rule for findings from SecurityHub

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-event-bridge, aws-security-hub

I am trying to create a EventBridge Rule for a "event" pattern as below :

[image]

My Json Structure :

```
{
    "Findings": [
        {
            "SchemaVersion": "2018-10-08",
            "Id": "arn:aws:securityhub:us-west-2:220307202362:subscription/aws-foundational-security-best-practices/v/1.0.0/EC2.9/finding/eeecfc8d-cb70-4686-8615-52d488f87959",
            "ProductArn": "arn:aws:securityhub:us-west-2::product/aws/securityhub",
            "ProductName": "Security Hub",
            "CompanyName": "AWS",
            "Region": "us-west-2",
            "GeneratorId": "aws-foundational-security-best-practices/v/1.0.0/EC2.9",
            "AwsAccountId": "220311111111",
            "Types": [
                "Software and Configuration Checks/Industry and Regulatory Standards/AWS-Foundational-Security-Best-Practices"
            ],
            "FirstObservedAt": "2021-09-27T20:01:59.019Z",
            "LastObservedAt": "2021-10-12T16:35:29.556Z",
            "CreatedAt": "2021-09-27T20:01:59.019Z",
            "UpdatedAt": "2021-10-12T16:35:29.556Z",
            "Severity": {
                "Product": 0,
                "Label": "INFORMATIONAL",
                "Normalized": 0,
                "Original": "INFORMATIONAL"
            },
            "Title": "EC2.9 EC2 instances should not have a public IPv4 address"
            }
            ]
            }
```

My Json structure does not looks like Event pattern shown in above picture on right hand side so i thought of modifying the event pattern something like as per my json posted above.As soon as i Edit the event pattern the option on the left hand side changes to "custom pattern" as below :

[image]

When i try to test my above json it gives me error as below :

[image]

What I am missing here ? How I can configure my event Hub findings such that it is able to identify my above json and it go go to my target (Kinesis firehose) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In test event pattern, you need write full event including items like version, id,...

This [tutorial](https://event-driven-architecture.workshop.aws/2-event-bridge/2-rules/rules.html#rule-matching-basics) shows simple example (for EC2 though).

And for Security Hub Findings, event test pattern will be like shown in [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/securityhub/latest/userguide/securityhub-cwe-event-formats.html) .

---

Update:

Here is the screenshot what I tried using your JSON. Note that Event pattern is only "source". And for Test event pattern headers except findings, I took codes from "Use sample event provided by AWS" of dropdown of custom event.

[image]

Event pattern JSON is:

```
{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "8e5622f9-d81c-4d81-612a-9319e7ee2506",
  "detail-type": "Security Hub Findings - Imported",
  "source": "aws.securityhub",
  "account": "123456789012",
  "time": "2019-04-11T21:52:17Z",
  "region": "us-west-2",
  "resources": ["arn:aws:securityhub:us-west-2::product/aws/macie/arn:aws:macie:us-west-2:123456789012:integtest/trigger/6294d71b927c41cbab915159a8f326a3/alert/f2893b211841"],
  "detail": {
        "Findings": [{
                "SchemaVersion": "2018-10-08",
                "Id": "arn:aws:securityhub:us-west-2:111122223333:subscription/aws-foundational-security-best-practices/v/1.0.0/EC2.9/finding/eeecfc8d-cb70-4686-8615-52d488f87959",
                "ProductArn": "arn:aws:securityhub:us-west-2::product/aws/securityhub",
                "ProductName": "Security Hub",
                "CompanyName": "AWS",
                "Region": "us-west-2",
                "GeneratorId": "aws-foundational-security-best-practices/v/1.0.0/EC2.9",
                "AwsAccountId": "220311111111",
                "Types": [
                        "Software and Configuration Checks/Industry and Regulatory Standards/AWS-Foundational-Security-Best-Practices"
                ],
                "FirstObservedAt": "2021-09-27T20:01:59.019Z",
                "LastObservedAt": "2021-10-12T16:35:29.556Z",
                "CreatedAt": "2021-09-27T20:01:59.019Z",
                "UpdatedAt": "2021-10-12T16:35:29.556Z",
                "Severity": {
                        "Product": 0,
                        "Label": "INFORMATIONAL",
                        "Normalized": 0,
                        "Original": "INFORMATIONAL"
                },
                "Title": "EC2.9 EC2 instances should not have a public IPv4 address"
        }]
  }
}
```

You can now use Test Event.

It's confusing that Event pattern and Test Event pattern is too far. The attributes like source is treated in EventBridge automatically.

For detecting specific attribute, "Event type->Security Hub Findings-Imported" might be useful.

Comment: I think what I have noticed is the security hub findings getting generated on my Free AWS account has different schema than above link. Please see my above json structure for security hub findings. In above findings I don't have any attribute like source, account etc. rather i have ProductName, companyname etc. Please suggest

Comment: Updated. Event pattern of EventBridge is confusing. When I use this, I create small pattern and do try-errors...